# Проверить состояние checkBox из другого файла python

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

По клику кнопки `pushButton` требуется выполнить функцию `check()`, которая описана в файле **function.py**.

Если выполнить код в таком виде, то возникает ошибка:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'check' from partially initialized module 'function' (most likely due to a circular import) (J:\project\QT_test\function.py)

Прошу подсказать, как проверить состояние `checkBox` из другого файла `*.py`

---

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from form import Ui_MainWindow
import sys
from function import check

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()

ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(check)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**form.py**

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(474, 120)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 81, 17))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 10, 271, 31))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

**function.py**

```
from main2 import ui

def check ():
    if ui.checkBox.checkState():
        ui.textBrowser.append('Checked!')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный `Qt Designer`. Создайте другой класс,
который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Если вы собираетесь использовать в модуле **function.py**  виджеты объектов, которые созданы в **main.py** - вам надо в функцию `check` передать экземпляр класса `Example`, чтобы иметь доступ к экземплярам этого класса.

Для передачи дополнительных параметров в функцию, по событию нажатия кнопки
можно использовать `lambda`.

```
#                                             vvvv
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: check(self))
#                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Попробуйте так:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from form import Ui_MainWindow           
from function import check
      

class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: check(self))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**form.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(474, 120)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 81, 17))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 10, 271, 31))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

---

**function.py**

```
def check(parent):
    if parent.checkBox.checkState():
        parent.textBrowser.append('Checked!')
    else:
        parent.textBrowser.append('Not Checked!')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А не могли бы Вы прокомментировать свой код, что бы понимать на будущее.

Comment: @tobsik я добавил для вас некоторые пояснения.